# Cannot convert value of type '(SwipeableTabBarController).Type' to expected argument type 'UIView'

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I want to add Tabbar to my application. But when I try to add it, it gives the error in the header. How do I activate the Tabbar function?

```
public extension UIViewController { 
    public func setTabBarSwipe(enabled: Bool) {
        if let swipeTabBarController = tabBarController as? SwipeableTabBarController {
            swipeTabBarController.isSwipeEnabled = enabled
        }
    }
}

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(SwipeableTabBarController)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a user defined type `SwipeableTabBarController` tab as a subview here

```
 view.addSubview(SwipeableTabBarController)
```

you need to add an instance like

```
 let vc = SwipeableTabBarController()
 self.addChild(vc)
 vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds
 view.addSubview(vc.view)
 vc.willMove(toParent:self)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your tabBarController is the root view controller of the app, use this, please.

```
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, 
           let tabBar = window.rootViewController as? SwipeableTabBarController {                 
             tabBar.isSwipeEnabled = enabled
        }
```